# Table relationships Many to many without a middle table in sql?

Tags: java, sql

I am making an app that can lookup creatures and am in the process atempting to increase my knowledge.

I have a table Creatures  and a table Skills

A creature and have multiple skills and a skill can be used by multiple creatures.

I am coding in java using sql manager.

I am using 1,2 to represent skills in the creature table and reference the skills table using the numerical values.

One thought I had was is there a way to make an overloaded stored procedure?

I have not started coding yet as I am still planning but would appreciate any ideas sent my way.

I am not trying to avoid the middle table just see if there is a way to do it another way that is not so hard its pointless.

Comment: Which database server? Does it support multi-valued columns?

Comment: Your choice of database design may have unintended [consequences](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8067580#8067580).

Comment: Facepalm @Mark Storey-Smith

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will probably need the middle table.

Storing a comma-separated list of skills in the Creatures table makes it easy to fetch the skills per creature, but what if you ever want to know the creatures who have a given skill?

Comma-separated lists are fraught with problems.  You can use them to optimize *one* way of accessing the data, but that causes a drastic de-optimization of *other* ways of accessing the data.

See also my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by fraught with problems? +1

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that. Would it make a difference if say each creature could only have up to 5 skills? Not trying to chase this way of doing it just trying everything for the sake of learning :)

Comment: @user1698308, nope it won't make a diffference. It is a bad idea almost 100% of the time to store data in a comma delimited list. Do not do it. Why are you against having a separate table to put the information in?

Comment: As I stated in my question I am not against it just exploring other means of doing stuff to flush out my skills.

Comment: @w0051977, see the answer I linked to for examples of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I now know never to do that and will not do it.

Comment: @user1698308, the only time it's valid to store comma-separated lists in a database is when you treat the *list* as an atomic, irreducible data element.  That is, you're never going to use SQL semantics to access individual elements of the list for searching, sorting, joining, counting, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a relational database, the "right" and general way to solve it is with a table that will store the relation.
If you want to avoid the middle table, you can put a constraint on the maximum number of skills per creature - let's say max 5 skills, and then have fields called skill1, skill2, ..., skill5. I cannot recommend this option, because it will make querying much more complicated, but for some cases it's possible. 
Another improvement of this option, would be a single int or long field, where each bit represents a skill. Still not good in my opinion though.

Comment: Thanks, from what I have gathered from the answers I have received this is just one big bad idea. Thanks for your input though.